# How to hide element using css only without id or class

Tags: css, class

How to hide the second list - "account" using css only while no class and id.
I am not able to change the html!

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a aria-controls="menu" href="#menu">Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a aria-controls="account" href="#account">Account</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Go through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#tree-structural_pseudo-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your css.

```
li:nth-child(2)
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

nth child of a tag means the nth occurance of a tag in any particular level. Here li:nth-child(2) means the 2nd li tag inside the ul tag.

Learn more about it
[here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 3):

this way

```css
ul > li:nth-of-type(2) {
  display : none;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <a aria-controls="menu" href="#menu">Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a aria-controls="account" href="#account">Account</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```